# Tengo un problema al enviar datos de compra por correo, utiliizo un array para agregarla al carrito de compras

Tags: php

```
public function enviarCarrito()
{
    $xResponse = new Response(); 
    $carrito=(isset($_SESSION['carrito']));
    $body = "Detalle de Pedido \n" ;
    foreach($carrito as $elemento) //me marca error en el foreach
    {
        $Producto= new Producto($elemento); 
        $body .= "Nombre: " .  $elemento->nombre  . "\n";
        $body .= "Precio: " .  $elemento->precio  . "\n";
        $body .= "Periodo: " .  $elemento->periodicidad . "\n";
    }
    //$cantidad = $val['cantidad'];  
    $from="example1@codigobit.com"; //cuenta que envia 
    $sdestinatario="example@hotmail.com"; //cuenta destino 
    $ssubject="Compra de Productos"; //subject 
    $header="From:".$from."\nReply-To:".$from."\n"; 
    $header=$header."X-Mailer:PHP/".phpversion()."\n"; 
    $header=$header."Mime-Version: 1.0\n"; 
    $header=$header."Content-Type: text/html"; 
    $enviado= mail($sdestinatario, utf8_decode($body),$ssubject,$header);
    if ($enviado)
    {
    $xResponse->script("toastr.success('En breve contestaremos su requerimiento')"); 
    $xResponse->script('parent.location.reload()');
    }
    else
    {
    $xResponse->script("toastr.error('Lo sentimos, datos no enviados')");
    //$xResponse->script('parent.location.reload()');
    }
    return $xResponse;
}
```

Comment: Si quitas `isset()` en `$carrito = $_SESSION['carrito'];` ?... y cambiar `$elemento->nombre` en `$Producto->nombre` ?

Comment: Realice los cambios sugeridos pero ahora me marca este error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Tienes que validar la variable `$carrito` es decir tiene que ser de tipo array... que te imprime cuando haces `var_dump($carrito);` ?

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
}
{"jxnobj":[{"cmd":"js","data":"toastr.error('Lo sentimos, datos no enviados')"}]}

Comment: Entonces como puedo hacer la validación de la variable $carrito para que sea tipo array.,?

Comment: Prueba con [json-decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: La descripción de la pregunta podría especificar con más detalle cuál es el problema. ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta pensando en alguien que les tú publicación y quiera entender cuál es el problema sin tener que analizar tú código? ¿Cuál es la pregunta?